# How to create a DataTable with a dynamic columns structure?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, datatables

I need to construct a DataTable that will not have pre-defined columns in my MVC project. The ammount of columns should be defined after the quantity of existing data in a field of the DB.

I have a field in my Model called Low Tier ID, it's a FK from another table (Low Tier table). I need to create columns for each Low Tier ID registered in the database. Aside that, the columns can't have the Low Tier ID as the title of the header, they need to show the Low Tier Name as titles, field one that I need to get by the FK.

The data that will be showed will be from the Quantity field (field from the Base Hour table, main table of the View). Each cholumn should be able to show the respective Quantites to the Low Tier ID of the column.

Until now, I was trying to create columns in this way below, but still without putting the data that the fields will be supposed to show and not even the right titles for the header.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var colsBaseLT = [];
function CreateColumnsBH() {
$.ajax({
    url: urlLTList, //refers to the LT List method from the Controller
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    aynsc: false,
    success: function (result) {
        //the result comeback an array of Low Tier Ids
        //The function below iterate an Array and try to create a columns for each element on it 
        var ltLength = result.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < ltLength; i++) {
            colsBaseLT.push({ data: null, orderable: false, className: 'col-sm-2 text-center', title: "titulo", defaultContent: '' });
        }
    }
});


function CreateTableBH() {
$.ajax({
    url: urlCreateTableBH, //refers to the GetBaseHour method from the Controller
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        dataTableBH = DataTablesAjaxScrollHeight('#tableBaseHour', colsBaseLT, result.Grid, null, "350px");
    }
}); 

$(document).ready(function () {
    CreateColumnsBH();
    DataTablesAjaxPagination("#tableBaseHour", colsBaseLT, null, null, 12, 'BaseHour');
    CreateTableBH();
}
```

**CONTROLLER (C#)**

```
    public JsonResult GetBaseHour()
    {
        //get the data from the Base Hour table, the main table of the View
        return Json(new { Grid = new BaseHourBusiness().GetList<BaseHour>(Util.AuxiliaryMethods.BMPerRequestInstance)});
    }

    public JsonResult LTList()
    {
        var lowTierList = new LowTierBusiness().GetList<LowTier>(Util.AuxiliaryMethods.BMPerRequestInstance).Select(
                s => new
                {
                    s.Name
                }).ToList();
        //in the Join above I try to get the LowTierNames of the Low Tier table
        return Json(lowTierList);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? And you are going to try and show a table in your View with any n number of columns based on some integer value? What happens if n > 20 or worse yet, n > 50. I'd hate to have to try and scroll through a webpage to view 20+ columns in a table.

Comment: The question is how can I do a DataTable with a undefined quantity of columns (this quantity is defined according to the ammount of 'Low Tier Ids') and how can I show the data respective to these columns. 

The DataTable will have to show every single field as a column, even with the scroll, because it's not expected that the DB will have a lot of registers of that field.

Comment: you may need to recreate the DataTable when you get a different list of columns, I don't see an API for changing columns, just show or hide.

Comment: But how can I assign the right data to the fields (the 'Quantities') of these undefined columns?